# Помогите в составлении регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Я пока только учусь составлять ругулярки сам, по этому прошу прощения за глупый вопрос.
Пробую составить регулярку для поля названия - оно может содержать буквы латиницы и кирилицы, цифры, пробелы а так же символы _ - и двойные ковычки пробую вот так но у меня естественно не работает или работа не корректно подскажите пожалуйста как надо? особенно сильно не приветствует пробелы

```
$ss = "дА 93434";

if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я1-9-_\"]+$/",$ss)) { 
echo "da";
} else {
echo "nyet";
}
```

Comment: и что вы ожидаете от вашего кода? что не работает?

Comment: пробела в маске нет, вот и не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сервис http://regexr.com/ - онлайн подбор регурярок, + подсказки при наведении.
http://take.ms/8m65p

Comment: спасибо довольно удобный сервис! Сваял в нем такую вот халабуду но только почему то она требует что бы в начале обязательно стояли пара латинских букв к примеру чисто кирилицу не пропускает(  и так и не разобрался как разрешать ввод двойных кавычек(  /([A-z0-9 - _ ])\w+/

Comment: ^-такой знак вначале говорит проверять с первого символа. Т.е. "^[a-z]+" - строка должна начинаться с 1 и более латинских символов, а потом проверять по Вашей регулярки. По поводу кириллиц, они не входят в диапазон A-z, надо добавить А-я. " - не есть спецсимволом для регулярки их можно просто добавить в перечень символов http://take.ms/MZnQD. Если они возможно в начале начните регулярное выражение так: ^"?[A-z]+